# Table with solutions of NDSolveValue and FindRoot for each parameter value

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

I kindly ask if someone could help me solve this problem:

I have solved a differential equation by varying a parameter that I called by $\alpha$ as follows:

```
n=1;
solution = 
 Table[NDSolveValue[{(D[ω[z], {z, 2}] + 2/z*D[ω[z], z] - 
        5*α*
         D[ω[z], z]^2) + (1 + α*(4*n + 18)*ω[
           z])*ω[z]^n == 0, ω[0.0001] == 
     1, ω'[0.0001] == 0}, ω, {z, 0.0001, 10}, 
   MaxSteps -> 1000], {α, 0, 0.5, 0.01}];
```

After that,  I found the first root for each function resulting from the above solution according to the $\alpha$ value:

```
For[ i = 0, i <= 50, i++,q = FindRoot[a[[i]][z], {z, firstzero, 0, 10}]; Print[q]]
```

I would like to construct a table where I can have all the values of $\alpha$, the solutions of differential equation according to $\alpha$, the first root of solutions according to  $\alpha$, and also I would like to include in this table the results of the following calculations (for each value of $\alpha$):

```
x = -z^2*((1 - (4*n + 18)*α*ω[z])*(D[ω[z], {z, 
      2}] + 2/z*D[ω[z], z]) - 
 5*α*D[ω[z], z]^2) /. solution
m = NIntegrate[x, {z, 0.0001, firstroot}]
```

I want to export this table and use its data to plot some graphics.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I would include your auxiliary integral into the ODE, and then use [`WhenEvent`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WhenEvent) to find the first zero crossing:

```
n = 1;
pf[α_] := Block[{z0},
    NDSolveValue[
        {
        ω''[z] + 2/z ω'[z] - 5 α ω'[z]^2 + (1 + α (4 n+18) ω[z]) ω[z]^n == 0,
        ω[0.0001]==1, ω'[0.0001]==0,
        int'[z] == -z^2 ((1 - (4 n+18) α ω[z]) (ω''[z] + 2/z ω'[z]) - 5 α ω'[z]^2),
        int[0.0001]==0,
        WhenEvent[ω[z]==0, z0 = z; "RemoveEvent"]
        },
        {ω, z0, int[z0]},
        {z,0.0001,10},
        MaxSteps->1000
    ]
]
```

The function `pf` returns the interpolating function, the crossing point and the integral. For example:

```
pf[.05]
```

> {InterpolatingFunction[Domain: {{0.0001,10.}} Output: scalar],
>   2.5631,1.06507}

*(It is also possible to use [`ParametricNDSolveValue`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ParametricNDSolveValue), but in that case capturing the zero crossing with a global variable doesn't work well)*

Comment: Thank you! It worked very well.